# Combinatorics on rooks on chess board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can five identical rooks be placed on the squares of an 8-by-8 board so that four of them form the corners of a rectangle with sides parallel to the sides of the board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we make the rectangle: for that, we just have to choose two rows and two columns, which gives us $\binom{8}{2}^2 = 784$ options. Then, we want to put down the final rook, which gives us $60$ further options, for a total of $784 \times 60 = 47040$ options.

Note that we have only counted each configuration once, since five rooks form at most one rectangle.

Comment: Isn't there 64 options for placing just the first rook?  There would be many rectangles you can create using that initial square.

Comment: Oops. My bad. You have to choose *two* rows and *two* columns, of course. That is $\binom{8}{2}^2$, not $8^2$. Will update.

Comment: Will you check answer to see where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was my first try:

Choose 1st rook: $\binom{64}{1}$

Choose location of 2nd rook in same row: $\binom{7}{1}$

Choose location of 3rd rook in same column (as 1st rook): $\binom{7}{1}$

This leaves one option for the 4th rook to complete the rectangle.

Place the final rook: $\binom{60}{1}$

Multiply them together to get 188,160.

What do you guys think about my answer?

Comment: You still need to divide by 4; you have counted each configuration four times, once for each corner of the rectangle.